# On macOS, how do I clear the previous bad returns in iTerm2?

Tags: macos, iterm2

I want to permanently clear the bad returns in iTerm2. I have used "Clear" and "command-k" etc including with "l" shortcuts but it apparently only clears the current terminal. If I restart the terminal, the bad returns appear at the beginning.

How can I clear them permanently?[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Thank you for any insight.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d06kA.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The image you linked to shows errors that are happening as your shell tries to execute the commands it is finding in the .zprofile and .zshrc files.  Every time you open a new terminal window it invokes a new shell process and that process reads these files.

The way to remove the error messages is to solve the errors.  The numbers appearing between the colon characters are the line number where each error was encountered.  It looks like you need to edit these two files to fix the errors.  Or possibly change the filenames to ones your shell won't read (for example .zprofile.donotuse and .zshrc.donotuse)  However, it's not clear whether you need these files for the good commands in them (if any).